# AdvancedDataGrid : Conditionally change the icon of the leaf node

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

**Introduction:** I have a flat ArrayCollection of object's, which i group to create the dataProvider for an AdvancedDataGrid. In this AdvancedDataGrid i have different branches representing different type of tasks. I want to conditionally change the icon for the leaf nodes in the AdvancedDataGrid based on a date field stored in each object.

For this purpose lets say each *Task* object contains an *id* and an *updatedDate* (Representing when the task was last updated). If the task has not been updated in the last five days (*updatedDate*+5 < today) the icon of that leaf node(*Task*) should be red, in constrast to the opposite the leaf icon in the AdvancedDatagrid should be green, e.g. like the image below. In this case task 35 has not been updated in the last 5 days, while 13 and 39 have.

[image]

**Question:** How do i change the leaf icons in the ADG based on the updatedDate of the underlying object? I would think that i have to extend AdvancedDataGrid and override some method, but which and how? Any type of guidance for achieving this particular task is much appriciated!

I have seen easy ways of changing the open and closed icons on the web, but no way of conditionally changing an open node's icon :)

**Update:** After applying @takteek groupIconFunction solution which always returned the same icon:

[image]

The problem is that I need the leaf node's icons changed, and not the branches.

**SOLVED**: Used @takteek's answer, with the exception of using iconFunction instead of groupIconFunction, because i wanted to change the leaf node's icons, and not the groupIcons :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two options are:

1. Specify a`groupIconFunction` for the data grid. This gets passed the current item and you return which icon to use, or null to use the default.
2. Create a subclass of AdvancedDataGrid and override `makeListData`. This function is responsible for creating the AdvancedDataGridListData object that gets passed to the renderers. You can change the `icon` and `disclosureIcon` properties on the list data to what you want. This is probably unnecessary unless you need more control.
3. Create your own item renderer based on `AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer`.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, and providing different alternatives. As i understand it the groupIconFunction seems like the easiest way to go for my task. But when i attempted to implement a simplified groupIconFunction which always returns the same icon, it only replaces the icon for the branches/parents in the ADG, and not the leaf nodes. Does the groupIconFunction only work for parent nodes/branches? Or also for leaf nodes? :)

Comment: `private function adgIconFunction(item:Object, value:int):Class 
   {
    return imageicon;
   } `

Comment: Updated my intital question to show you what the ADG looked like after applying this simplified groupIconFunction

Comment: @Sebastian Sorry about that. I meant to mention iconFunction also but somehow I forgot while I was writing the answer.